# Why this pointer to pointer to char is current?

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-to-pointer

```
char *array[10];

char **ptr = array;
```

In my opinion, the structure of first sentence is below diagram:

[image: Diagram]

But the last sentence, whether this array equal array [0]? 
And ptr pointer to array[0],array[0] pointer to char?
If that's right, How can I draw this diagram of structure ?

Comment: The 1st is an array of pointers to char(s). The diagram is correct, but usually in C, since convention says a "string" is a number of chars which last is the 8-bit integer value zero, you could draw more chars after the first, for the sake of genericity.

Comment: "ptr" is the arrow coming down from the top into first cell of array

Comment: The pointer is pointing to `array[0]` which is the same as `*array` and all pointers involved will be pointers to `char`.

Answer (score 1):

ptr is pointer to the first element of the array, ptr[0] or array[0] is pointer to the first element of null-terminated string. I got diagram from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh184278(v=vs.88).aspx as an illustration

[image: Stucture]

Answer (score 1):

With this instruction `char *array[10];` you are declaring an array of 10 elements of (char *), namely of char pointers.

[image]

`char **ptr = array;` is a pointer to a pointer to char like the below schema (`ptr` is `argv`, `array` is `argc`):

[image]